# Evitar que TempData Se vuelva null al recargar vista

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Tengo un problema con `TempData` al refrescar la vista.

Este `controller` asigna un `string` a `TempData`:

```
public ActionResult Sucursales(string rfcCompany)
{
    model.CuentaUser = CuentaUser;
    TempData["RFCCompany"] = rfcCompany;//solo para evitar mandar el rfc por la url nuevamente
    return View(model);
}
```

Estando en la vista `Sucursales.cshtml` redirecciono a `DetalleSucursal.cshtml`, el cual el controlador tiene esto:

```
public ActionResult DetalleSucursal(int id, int idEmpresa, string CuentaUser){
    ComprobantesModel model = new ComprobantesModel();
    model.idEmpresa = idEmpresa;
    model.idSucursal = id;
    model.CuentaUser = CuentaUser;
    ViewBag.RFCCompany = TempData["RFCCompany"] as string;//para mostrar el RFC en algun lugar de la vista
    return View(model);
}
```

No tengo problema con la primera carga de la vista, el problema viene cuando refresco la vista `DetalleSucursal.cshtml` el `TempData["RFCCompany"]` se carga en el controlador como `null` como si no se hubiese cargado desde el controlador `Sucursales`. **¿Cómo puedo evitar que el `TempData["RFCCompany"]` no se vuelva `null` al refrescar la página `DetalleSucursal.cshtml`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si no deseas utilizar una variable de sesión lo adecuado es utilizar el `TempData` en conjunto con el método `Keep` para ir acarreando la información entre *redirects*. La documentación oficial dice:

> Los datos en un objeto TempDataDictionary persiste sólo de una
>   solicitud a la siguiente, a menos que marques una o más claves para
>   retenerlas utilizando el método `Keep`.

Para mantener todas las entradas del diccionario `TempData` es con:

```
TempData.Keep();
```

Para mantener una entrada del diccionario `TempData` se tiene que especificar una llave:

```
TempData.Keep("RFCCompany");
```

En tu caso y una prueba que realicé y me funcionó fue que en el `Controller` se especifica el valor de la misma forma que tú lo definiste:

```
public ActionResult Sucursales(string rfcCompany)
{
    model.CuentaUser = CuentaUser;
    TempData["RFCCompany"] = rfcCompany;//solo para evitar mandar el rfc por la url nuevamente
    return View(model);
}
```

Solo se tendría que agregar el siguiente segmento de código del lado de la vista, el lugar es indiferente pero por organización del código recomendaría que fuese al inicio:

```
@{
    TempData.Keep("RFCCompany");
}
```

De esta forma, para futuros *redirects* la información estaría viajando entre las peticiones.

Referencias:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary(v=vs.118).aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.tempdatadictionary.keep(v=vs.118).aspx

Answer (score 2):

`TempData` tiene un tiempo de vida muy corto (solo hasta que termina de cargar la vista).

Como alternativa en lugar de `TempData` podrias utilizar `Session` que mantendra la data mientras dure la `session` o hasta que la elimines manualmente.

```
public ActionResult Sucursales(string rfcCompany)
{
  model.CuentaUser = CuentaUser;
  Session["RFCCompany"] = rfcCompany;
  return View(model);
}


public ActionResult DetalleSucursal(int id, int idEmpresa, string CuentaUser)
{
  ComprobantesModel model = new ComprobantesModel();
  model.idEmpresa = idEmpresa;
  model.idSucursal = id;
  model.CuentaUser = CuentaUser;
  ViewBag.RFCCompany = Session["RFCCompany"] as string;
  return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Solo hay una cuestión que me comento otro usuario de aquí, _al servidor le cuesta recursos mantener una sesión_, y eso es lo que principalmente quisiera evitar, pero es buena solución para en lo que empieza a crecer el  proyecto

Comment: TempData utiliza Session para almacenar el valor de la variable, al utilizar TempData el valor dura solo 1 request (1 carga de vista). Según lo que solicitas necesitas que te dure para 2 request, por lo cual puedes almacenar el valor en un Session y luego eliminar el valor manualmente cuando ya no lo requieras.

Answer (score 0):

Una alternativa es guardar la informacion del lado del cliente ya sea con `localStorage` o `sessionStorage` (`Web Storage`).

Para saber si un navegador soporta `Web Storage` utilizamos este fragmento de código:

```
if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    // Si soporta Web Storage.
} else {
    // Lo siento! No Soporta Web Storage tu navegador...
}
```

---

Ahora `sessionStorage` es accesibles mientras dura la sesión de navegación. Los datos no son recuperables si:

1. Se cierra el navegador y se vuelve a abrir.
2. Se abre una nueva pestaña de navegación independiente y se sigue
   navegando en esa pestaña.
3. Se cierra la ventana de navegación que se estuviera utilizando y se
   abre otra.

Ejemplo obtenido de w3school: <kbd>[Demo w3school sessionStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_webstorage_session)</kbd>

```js
function clickCounter() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (sessionStorage.clickcount) {
      sessionStorage.clickcount = Number(sessionStorage.clickcount) + 1;
    } else {
      sessionStorage.clickcount = 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have clicked the button " + sessionStorage.clickcount + " time(s) in this session.";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
  }
}
```

```html
<p><button onclick="clickCounter()" type="button">Click me!</button></p>
<div id="result"></div>
<p>Click the button to see the counter increase.</p>
<p>Close the browser tab (or window), and try again, and the counter is reset.</p>
```

Esto es lo mas adaptable a mi problemática ya que no requiero que los datos se mantengan por mucho tiempo a como lo es localStorage

---

**¿Pero qué ocurre si quisiéramos almacenar esa información más allá de una sesión y que estuviera disponible tanto si se cierra el navegador y se vuelve a abrir como si se continúa navegando en una ventana distinta de la inicial?**

Esto trata de ser respondido por `localStorage`. Este objeto tiene las mismas propiedades y métodos que `sessionStorage`, pero su persistencia va más allá de la sesión.

Los datos no son recuperables si:

1. Se limpia la cache del navegador.

Ejemplo obtenido de w3school:<kbd>[Demo w3school localStorage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_webstorage_local_clickcount)</kbd>

```js
function clickCounter() {
  if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
    if (localStorage.clickcount) {
      localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount) + 1;
    } else {
      localStorage.clickcount = 1;
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have clicked the button " + localStorage.clickcount + " time(s).";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
  }
}
```

```html
<p><button onclick="clickCounter()" type="button">Click me!</button></p>
<div id="result"></div>
<p>Click the button to see the counter increase.</p>
<p>Close the browser tab (or window), and try again, and the counter will continue to count (is not reset).</p>
```

Comment: avanzas rápido hermano :D #DaleConTodoElPower2.0!!!